# Why do I keep getting Error: Invalid Value Promise { <pending> } when using sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, mysql2

I'm trying to create a user authentication route on an express web server using Sequelize to access my MySql database. The part I'm stuck on is I'm trying to authenticate my db connection, initialize my `User` model, and populate said Model with test login info. But I keep getting `Error: Invalid value Promise { <pending. }` some where in the process.

Here is my code:

```
import {Sequelize, DataTypes} from 'sequelize'
import argon2 from 'argon2'
const sequelize = new Sequelize('DATABASE', 'USERNAME', PASSWORD, {
    port: PORT,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    schema: 'SCHEMA',
});
sequelize.authenticate()
    .then(_ => console.log('db connected'))
    .then(_ => sequelize.define('User', {
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: 'compositeIndex'
        },
        passwordHash: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: 'compositeIndex'
        }
    }))
    .then(() => console.log('define'))
    .then(_ => sequelize.sync())
    .then(() => console.log('sync'))
    .then(_ => sequelize.models.User.findOrCreate({
        where: {
            email: 'test@test.com',
            passwordHash: argon2.hash('goodPassword', { type: argon2.argon2i })
        }
    }))
    .then(() => console.log('create'))
    .then(_ => sequelize.save())
    .then(() => console.log('save'))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))

export default sequelize
```

Here's the almost the exact same thing without using .then

```
const getSequelizeAwait = async () => {
    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate()
        const User = await sequelize.define('User', {
            email: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
                unique: 'compositeIndex'
            },
            passwordHash: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
                unique: 'compositeIndex'
            }
        })
        await sequelize.sync()
        await User.findOrCreate({
            where: {
                email: 'test@test.com',
                passwordHash: argon2.hash('goodPassword', { type: argon2.argon2i })
            }
        })
        await sequaleize.save()
        return sequelize
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}
```

Either way I get this console output:

```
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
Executing (default): SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME = 'SCHEMA.User' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SCHEMA'
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `raffle.Users`
Executing (6336d9f9-fa98-49c2-9e73-9e7b243a844c): START TRANSACTION;
Executing (6336d9f9-fa98-49c2-9e73-9e7b243a844c): COMMIT;
Error: Invalid value Promise { <pending> }
    at Object.escape
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks `argon2` API is async.

try with:

```
const passwordHash = await argon2.hash('goodPassword', { type: argon2.argon2i })
await User.findOrCreate({
  where: {
    email: 'test@test.com',
    passwordHash 
   }
})
```